# Grow out a pollarded fruitless mulberry

Tags: tree-care, mulberry

In the backyard of our new house is a fruitless mulberry tree that is probably about 40 years old. It has been pollarded for probably the last 20 years about 3 feet out from where 5 major limbs emerge from the trunk -- these major limbs have grown into big nubs that are starting to merge into each other.

I'd really like to grow this tree out into a major shade tree with (hopefully) more normal-looking limbs and branches... Any idea how I should approach this problem?

(Note: this is in USDA hardiness zone 9b, in the USA)

Comment: Pictures help, can you add some?